Can I use 10/3 UF to power 4 outlets?
Is 10/3 uf Sufficient for 4 outlets 100' underground to detached garage from 50 amp sub panel?

What type of outlets?

10 gauge wire is usually limited to be fed by a 30 amp breaker.  Household outlets are limited to be on 15 or 20 amp breakers.  A bigger size sub panel can be used, even if you can only feed it with 30 amps.  Powering 4 outlets is no problem, unless running like 4 space heaters together.

@crip659 Or just use a 20 amp breaker on the 10 ga wire.

What are you plugging into these outlets?
